# QueryDSL coalesce in order by

Tags: jpa, jpql, querydsl

I'm trying to join two tables and output them and sort them alphabetically by two fields like `order by coalesce(tableA.name, tableB.name)` (NOT `order by tableA.name, tableB.name`), so result should be something like:

```
tableA.name    tableB.name
A              null
B              null
null           C
D              null
null           E
```

In plain SQL it works fine but when I try to do it with QueryDSL it adds additional column to generated select statement and sorts only by first specified column:

```
//java code
query.orderBy(qTableA.name.coalesce(qTableB.name).asc());

//generated sql code
SELECT ...
       COALESCE(tablea_.NAME, tableb_.NAME) AS col_9_0_
FROM   ...
WHERE  ...
ORDER  BY tablea1_.NAME ASC
```

Can somebody tell why it does it like that and whether it is possible to make it work as I expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
final Coalesce<String> coalesce =
    new Coalesce<>(String.class).add(optionalA).add(optionalB);
```

Use the coalesce in your select fields and so in your order by clause:

```
.orderBy(coalesce.asc()) // or desc()
```